# How to render multiple partial views without using Controller on the server side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am new to MVC3. I am using razor.

I have a menu with 4 items.
With each click, a different partial view should open.

Could anyone help me out here..

Preferably, without using a controller on server side..

Thanks, 
Aneesh

Comment: You should provide more information about what are you trying to accomplish. Do you want to dynamically load those views via ajax for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Html.RenderPartial is what you need if you don't what to use a controller:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial.aspx

If you want to render partial view using controller action then use Html.RenderAction:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/11/24/renderpartial-vs-renderaction.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object where all the data that you want show on the all the different partial views.
Then use @Html.RenderPartial to render your desired partial. Use the second parmater to add the data.

Example:
@{Html.RenderPartial("_Customers", Model.CustomerList);}

Comment: This example is invalid. Proper use: `@{Html.RenderPartial("_Customers", Model.CustomerList);}`